# Can a Tensorflow Datasets decoder have access to multiple features?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using the Kitti dataset in tensorflow datasets (tfds). It has a nested structure of object features:

```
FeaturesDict({
    'image': Image(shape=(None, None, 3), dtype=uint8),
    'image/file_name': Text(shape=(), dtype=string),
    'objects': Sequence({
        'alpha': float32,
        'bbox': BBoxFeature(shape=(4,), dtype=float32),
        'dimensions': Tensor(shape=(3,), dtype=float32),
        'location': Tensor(shape=(3,), dtype=float32),
        'occluded': ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=int64, num_classes=4),
        'rotation_y': float32,
        'truncated': float32,
        'type': ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=int64, num_classes=8),
    }),
})
```

Say I would like to extract a class `type_occluded` where each combination of `occluded` and `type` is an individual class. For this I need to access both features at a time or even the whole `objects` Sequence. Is it possible to define a Decoder that accesses a Sequence of features, or even just two features at a time?

I hoped to be able to hand over the whole `objects` Sequence to a custom Decoder, in the likes of

```
@tfds.decode.make_decoder()
def ObjectDecoder(x, features):
    return str(x["type"]) + str(x["occluded"])

decoder = {
    "image": ImageDecoder(),
    "objects": ObjectDecoder()
}
```

but handing over a decoder for the `objects` Sequence in general seems to be impossible, because TFDS expects a dict of dicts for `decoder`, one for each feature individually.